# bind attribute to object property in isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive (using an isolated scope) that makes use of another directive which changes a flag which I therefore had to put into a container object. Now, I also want to be able to set that flag from the outside. Let me "draw" this for you:

```
outerScope (outerFlag1 = true, outerFlag2 = true)
    directiveScope (container.flag1 = false, container.flag2 = false)
        subdirectiveScope (container.flag1 = false)
        subdirectiveScope (container.flag2 = false)
```

The flag variables in *directiveScope* and *subdirectiveScope* are always the same, because *container* is prototypically inherited. Now I want to be able to set it from the outside, to synchronize *outerFlagX* with *container.flagX*.

With the isolated scope definition I can map a property like so:

```
scope: {
        outerFlag1: '=flag1'
        outerFlag2: '=flag2'
       }
```

However, what I would need but is not allowed is

```
scope: {
        outerFlag1: '=container.flag1'
        outerFlag2: '=container.flag2'
       }
```

How can I get this done?

I added a plunker based on the one that Mikko provided (thanks a lot): http://plnkr.co/edit/hT6Zip

Comment: Well, it works (see plunker) with simply not using the container object. Although I still have to find out, why it still doesn't work in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem has two parts which are not entirely obvious from my question, so apologies for that.

1. Simply don't use the container object. (see the [plunkr in my question](http://plnkr.co/edit/hT6Zip))
2. While this worked in the plunker, it still didn't work in my code. So I stripped it down until it worked. The second problem was, that I used the sub-directives together with an **ng-if**. See a [modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hR8spJ) where one of the usages features an *ng-if* like so:

   `<sub-directive ng-if="condition" flag="flag2">
   </subdirective>`

Unfortunately (in this case), *ng-if* creates a child scope so that if the flag is modified in the sub-directive, it sets an own property in that child scope. As usual, this is not available in the parent scope (prototypical inheritance). Click on the parent checkbox first, it works as expected, clicking the sub-checkbox will break it.

So the solution is, to use **ng-show** instead, which does not create another scope.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been great to see a real-life use case, in form of a plunker/fiddle.
Your problem might go away just by not defining isolated scope in your subdirective.

Given you have following `controller` and two `directives`

```
// controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.model = null;
});

// top level directive
app.directive('oneDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      flag: '='
    },
    template: '<label for="one">One directive</label><br>' +
              '<input type="text" name="one" ng-model="flag">' +
              '<br>' + 
              '<other-directive></other-directive>'
  }; 
});

// nested directive
app.directive('otherDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<label for="other">Other directive</label><br>' +
              '<input type="text" name="other" ng-model="flag">'
  };
});
```

And related HTML template

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h4>Directive scopes</h4>
  <div>
    <label for="number">Parent scope</label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" placeholder="enter something..." />
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div>
    <one-directive flag="model"></one-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

That would give you something liek

[image: imgur]

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/7XhG8e

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Real world example is a panel that can have different states and toggles that can toggle those states. Your example is nice but is missing one thing (which I didn't mention): The sub-directive is used several times (that's why I created it as directive). I'm thinking about using ngModel for the subdirectives. What do you think? (edit: Stupid me, I'm already using ngModel.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It turned out, a very strange behavior made me jump through hoops so I ended up using the container object and ngModel etc. It worked to some extent but brought up the problem I described in the question.
If you're curious about the strange behavior: I have a link with _ng-click="flag = !flag"_. This link has a tooltip. That somehow breaks the evaluation of ng-click. I changed it to _ng-click="toggle()"_ and toggled the flag in a function. That works. I'll not investigate why...